# In angular 12 I need to call an api which will give token and then I need to pass that token to another api to call but my code is not working

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, rxjs

> Below is my code having two methods getToken and validateuser, I am
> taking the token from getToken and passing it to the parameter of validateuser. But before getting the token my second api calls is getting executed.

```
 ngOnInit(): void {
           this.login()
          }
getToken(){
    const authParam = {
      username: "abc",
      password: "abc"
    };
    this.apiService.getToken(authParam)
      .subscribe(
        response => {
          console.log("here1");
          this.token = response;  
          console.log(this.token);
        },
        error => {
          console.log(error);
        });
  }

    vlidateUser(){
    this.getToken();
    const loginParam ={
      userId:"abc",
      serviceType:"UV",
      auth_token:this.token
    }
    this.apiService.validateUser(loginParam)
    .subscribe(
      response => {
        console.log("here2");
        console.log(response);
      },
      error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }

  login(){
      this.vlidateUser();
  }
  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> - Use **async** before **vlidateUser()**
> - Use **await** before **this.getToken()**

```
 ngOnInit(): void {
   this.login()
 }
 getToken(){
     const authParam = {
       username: "abc",
       password: "abc"
     };
     this.apiService.getToken(authParam)
       .subscribe(
         response => {
            console.log("here1");
            this.token = response;  
            console.log(this.token);
         },
         error => {
          console.log(error);
         });
  }

  async vlidateUser(){
      await this.getToken();
      const loginParam ={
         userId:"abc",
         serviceType:"UV",
         auth_token:this.token
      }
      this.apiService.validateUser(loginParam)
        .subscribe(
          response => {
          console.log("here2");
          console.log(response);
        },
        error => {
          console.log(error);
        });
  }

  login(){
      this.vlidateUser();
  }
  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Use async await

```
    ngOnInit(): void {
           this.login()
          }
getToken(){
    const authParam = {
      username: "abc",
      password: "abc"
    };
    this.apiService.getToken(authParam)
      .subscribe(
        response => {
          console.log("here1");
          this.token = response;  
          console.log(this.token);
        },
        error => {
          console.log(error);
        });
  }

    async vlidateUser(){
    await this.getToken();
    const loginParam ={
      userId:"abc",
      serviceType:"UV",
      auth_token:this.token
    }
    this.apiService.validateUser(loginParam)
    .subscribe(
      response => {
        console.log("here2");
        console.log(response);
      },
      error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }

  login(){
      this.vlidateUser();
  }
  
}
```

Comment: I tried using asyc await but my validateuser api is getting executed first and in that token value is undefined.

Comment: try calling vlidateUser() inside gettoken subscribe

Comment: Yea, Its working but is a feasible way? Because before calling any api I have to call getToken api to generate token and pass it to another API

Comment: then you have to use async-await

Comment: @tripti is it resolved

Comment: Yes it is Resolved, need to convert getToken into promise and then using asyc await it got resolved. Thank you @Avinash

Comment: @tripi could you please vote to my answer as useful.

Comment: @Avinsha My reputation point is low, so can not vote.

Answer (score 0):

A better way to tackle this problem is to use mergeMap, switchMap operators instead of using async.

switchMap allows you to use the response of one observable *(getToken() API in your case)* in the next observable *(validateUser() API)*

```js
login() {
        const authParam = {
            username: 'abc',
            password: 'abc',
        };
        this.apiService
            .getToken(authParam)
            .pipe(
                switchMap(response => {
                    const token = response;
                    const loginParam = {
                        userId: 'abc',
                        serviceType: 'UV',
                        auth_token: token,
                    };
                    return this.apiService.validateUser(loginParam);
                })
            )
            .subscribe(
                (resp) => {
                    console.log('here2');
                    console.log(resp);
                },
                error => {
                    console.log(error);
                }
            );
    }
```

Your validateUser API will run only after getToken returns a value. I've used switchMap to use the latest getToken value *(if there are multiple API calls)*